# Why does heat engine not change its internal energy?

Tags: thermodynamics

> For a heat engine, the change of internal energy at the end of a cycle is zero.

Why is this true? I think this is merely an assumption and definition. Does it have a theoretical basis?

Comment: Where is this quote from?

Comment: Do you understand that heat engine operation can be described as tracing a (cyclic) path through the state space of the system?

Answer (score 3):

What would happen if the internal energy would be changed after a *cycle*? You would hardly can call that cyclic. Either the engine would deplete its internal energy, and after some time stop working (because its energy content is finite), or it would collect internal energy with each cycle which would lead to disintegration sooner or later.

The whole point of a cyclic heat engine is, that it is in its initial state after completing the cycle, so that it can begin the cycle again, transforming more heat to work.